# Apache Spark: How application level scheduling is done in spark standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, scheduler, scheduling, distributed-computing

**StandAlone Mode**

There is not so much information available on "Application level Scheduling" i.e how multiple applications are scheduled in spark standalone mode. Only this link http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html . The only thing that I have been able to find is that its a FIFO scheduler. As I understand standalone scheduling can also be done in static or dynamic mode. But I could not find any info about dynamic mode. Can someone explain the application scheduling in spark standalone mode in detail ?

Comment: you can configure # of cores, RAM per executor, anything on the SparkSession level. SparkSession = spark application. That's a dynamic configuration

Answer (score 0):

> info about dynamic mode.

This is when you dynamic configure the resources your application is going to use.

For example, you can configure the number of cores, the memory per executor, number of executors and so on.

Read more in [Dynamic Resource Allocation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation).